# What do we know about Dreg the dragon proper?

Tags: dragons

In Albanian Mythology, Dreg is mentioned to be the dragon proper. But, I can't find anything else about him. Save for the fact that Christianity demonized him and turned his name into one of the Albanian names for the Devil.

What do we know about the dragon proper?